# Why parallelization slows down my program?

Tags: go, concurrency

I have two programs. They solve a system of linear equations. Both of them work correctly (they produce the same result).

The first program works without concurrency.

the second program is very similar to the first, with the exception that I added parallelism in some places. These places are marked in code.

Here are two programs:

**First one. Without concurrency.**

```golang
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "math"
        "os"
        "time"
)

func main() {
        start := time.Now()
        N := 1000
        a := CreateRandomMatrix(N)
        b := CreateRandomVector(N)

        index := make([]int, len(a))
        for i := range index {
            index[i] = i
        }

        for i := 0; i < len(a); i++ {

            r := a[i][index[i]]

            var kk int

            var maxElemInRow float64
            for k := i; k < len(a); k++ {
                if math.Abs(a[i][index[k]]) > maxElemInRow {
                    kk = k
                    maxElemInRow = math.Abs(a[i][index[k]])
                }
            }

            index[i], index[kk] = index[kk], index[i]

            r = a[i][index[i]]

            if r == 0 {
                if b[i] == 0 {
                    fmt.Println("a lot of solutions")
                } else {
                    fmt.Println("no solutions")
                }
                os.Exit(1)
            }

            for j := 0; j < len(a[i]); j++ {
                a[i][index[j]] /= r
            }
            b[i] /= r

            for k := i + 1; k < len(a); k++ {
                r = a[k][index[i]]
                for j := 0; j < len(a[i]); j++ {
                    a[k][index[j]] = a[k][index[j]] - a[i][index[j]]*r
                }
                b[k] = b[k] - b[i]*r
            }

        }

        var x vector = make(vector, len(b))

        for i := len(a) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
            x[i] = b[i]

            for j := i + 1; j < len(a); j++ {
                x[i] = x[i] - (x[j] * a[i][index[j]])
            }
        }

        result := make([]string, len(x))
        for i, val := range index {
            result[val] = fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", x[i])
        }
        fmt.Println("tested part took:", time.Now().Sub(start))
    }
```

**The second one:**

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

const (
    workers = 8
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {

    start := time.Now()
    N := 1000
    a := CreateRandomMatrix(N)
    b := CreateRandomVector(N)

    index := make([]int, len(a))
    for i := range index {
        index[i] = i
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(a); i++ {

        r := a[i][index[i]]

        var kk int
        var max float64

        for k := i; k < len(a); k++ {
            if math.Abs(a[i][index[k]]) > max {
                kk = k
                max = math.Abs(a[i][index[k]])
            }
        }

        index[i], index[kk] = index[kk], index[i]

        r = a[i][index[i]]

        if r == 0 {
            if b[i] == 0 {
                fmt.Println("a lot of solutions")
            } else {
                fmt.Println("no solutions")
            }
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        // concurrency here
        for w := 0; w < workers; w++ {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func(w int) {
                start := len(a[i]) / workers * w
                end := len(a[i]) / workers * (w + 1)

                if end > len(a[i]) {
                    end = len(a[i])
                }

                for j := start; j < end; j++ {
                    a[i][index[j]] /= r
                }
                wg.Done()
            }(w)
        }

        b[i] /= r
        wg.Wait()

        for k := i + 1; k < len(a); k++ {
            r = a[k][index[i]]
            for j := 0; j < len(a[i]); j++ {
                a[k][index[j]] = a[k][index[j]] - a[i][index[j]]*r
            }
            b[k] = b[k] - b[i]*r
        }

    }

    var x vector = make(vector, len(b))

    for i := len(a) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        x[i] = b[i]

        for j := i + 1; j < len(a); j++ {
            x[i] = x[i] - (x[j] * a[i][index[j]])
        }
    }

    result := make([]string, len(x))
    for i, val := range index {
        result[val] = fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", x[i])
    }
    fmt.Println("tested part took:", time.Now().Sub(start))
}
```

**And an additional code block the same for both programs**

```
package main

import "math/rand"

type matrix [][]float64
type vector []float64

func CreateRandomMatrix(n int) matrix {
    m := make(matrix, n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        m[i] = make(vector, n)
        for j := 0; j < n; j++ {
            m[i][j] = float64(rand.Intn(100))
        }
    }
    return m
}

func CreateRandomVector(n int) vector {
    v := make(vector, n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        v[i] = float64(rand.Intn(100))
    }
    return v
}
```

**So. Here is the problem:**

In theory, the second program should run faster, because some calculations are distributed across the processor cores. But this does not occur. With each addition of the parallelism element, the second program begins to slow down.

I tested it for large values ​​of N, as well as for small ones. The running time of the second version of the program is significantly behind the first. For example, if you set N = 3500, the difference in execution will be about 10 seconds.

Also, if you set the number of workers to 1, the second program starts to work faster.

**Why it happens? Am I making a mistake somewhere? How can I make distributed computing speed up a program?**

**GO VERSION:** 1.14. But I also checked this code on version 1.13.

**ADD:** I found that if the program is served with large matrix sizes, then the parallel version begins to catch up with a sequential one.

**EDIT SUMMARY:** In the second program, a piece with parallelism was deleted in the place where `kk` and`max` are calculated to get rid of data races.

Comment: You're conflating parallelism and concurrency. In the current version of Go, goroutines are not preemptible, so goroutines with tight computation loops like yours will not yield to other goroutines. Your program may still benefit from multiple cores, but that depends on how those goroutines are scheduled.

Comment: Also note that your parallel version has data races. Run it with `--race` to see them. The compiler is allowed to rewrite your code such that the max check would not work as you expect, because it can assume that each goroutine is completely independent in its access to `maxElemInRow` and `kk`, and optimize accordingly. (For example, it can assume that `maxElemInRow` cannot be changed behind its back, so if it just wrote it, it doesn't have to read it. So goroutine A could write 5, then goroutine B write 10, then goroutine A write 7 since it's more than 5.)

Comment: @BurakSerdar: "In the current version of Go, goroutines are not preemptible, " False. Goroutines are now asynchronously preemptible. https://golang.org/doc/go1.14

Comment: @peterSO you're right, still on 1.13 here, time to upgrade. OP did not specify a version though...

Comment: You assume that you are CPU-bound. You may be memory-bound.

Comment: "In theory, the second program should run faster, because some calculations are distributed across the processor cores." That is not even true in theory, much less in practice. If the processor cores are not the bottleneck adding more might even make the throughput slower. Fast numerical algorithms on multicore/multiprocessor is a astonishingly hard problem. Take yourself a couple of years and read the relevant literature.

Comment: Please watch [Concurrency is not Parallelism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cN_DpYBzKso).  Choice quote: "They take a program. They run it on more processors, and it would get slower."

Comment: Also watch this.... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCdGlxBbKU4   the beginning has a interesting explanation about parallelismm and data races

Comment: @Volker Before doing this, I opened the appropriate literature with C# code, which gives recommendations for parallelizing this program and there are results that show a significant increase in speed.

Comment: @Rob Napier, You're right, i have data races. This happens in a piece of code with `maxElemInRow` and `kk`, as you said. So far, I have returned this piece to its original position, removing parallelism. I still have a loss in speed using 8 processor cores.

Comment: @wintermonth Can you please post the updated code in that case so we're talking about the same thing? (It's not meaningful to talk about the performance of code that isn't correct.) Thanks.

Comment: @Rob Napier, Done.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting up a lot of complexity here for a very small amount of work:

```
    for j := 0; j < len(a[i]); j++ {
        a[i][index[j]] /= r
    }
```

This requires N divisions, so about 1000 in your example. Plus some book-keeping.

You replace it with this:

```
            start := len(a[i]) / workers * w
            end := len(a[i]) / workers * (w + 1)

            if end > len(a[i]) {
                end = len(a[i])
            }

            for j := start; j < end; j++ {
                a[i][index[j]] /= r
            }
```

This performs 125 divisions (1000/8), plus 2 extra divisions plus two extra multiplies, plus an extra add and an extra subtract (that's how `>` is done), per row. The other bookkeeping is the same. So there's something like 3% computational overhead before you even get started. That's normal in concurrent work; I'm just reminding you that concurrent work always starts in a hole that it has to dig itself out of.

You add to that 8 goroutine creations and 16 WaitGroup operations (plus a Wait) per row. That's 1000s of goroutines created and destroyed. Goroutines are cheap but they're not *that* cheap. And they're definitely not cheap inside of a loop you run a thousand times.

And this is to speed up a piece of code that is, by my measurements, 0.05% of your loop. You're checking times based on the entire run (including creating the matrices in the first place). But when I test the main outer loop (N=1000), it's about 20ms (serial). The division loop is about 10µs. The division loop is not the interesting piece to spread across CPUs. A goroutine that only exists for 10µs is not a good use of resources.

You mention "Before doing this, I opened the appropriate literature with C# code, which gives recommendations for parallelizing this program and there are results that show a significant increase in speed." This doesn't look like it would be fast in C#, either. If you created 8 Tasks per row to do the division, I would expect that to have the same problems as in Go.

There is probably also memory locality issues at play here. It's much more efficient to haul memory up from RAM in chunks and operate on it sequentially than to jump around between areas of memory, invalidating the CPU caches and wasting parts of the cache line. (But I suspect this is overwhelmed by the cost of generating and destroying 8,000 goroutines.)

I'm actually quite amazed at how fast the concurrent code is.

Rather than picking single, small bits to run in parallel across cores, what you want to do is structure your algorithm so you can split up a lot of work to a small number of workers, rather than a little work to a lot of workers.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed analysis and explanation, everything is clear now!  I consider the issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to everyone who helped me and explained to me what I was wrong about. I looked at the code and found a place where it can be optimized by parallelizing the calculations and get a real increase in speed due to the validity of this approach in this place.

All the moments in which I tried to parallelize before, I returned to the initial sequential state.

The piece of code that I replaced using the parallel approach is marked with a comment.

**Here is the code:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

const (
    workers = 8
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    N := 3000

    a := CreateRandomMatrix(N)
    b := CreateRandomVector(N)
    start := time.Now()

    index := make([]int, len(a))
    for i := range index {
        index[i] = i
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(a); i++ {

        r := a[i][index[i]]

        var kk int
        var max float64

        for k := i; k < len(a); k++ {
            if math.Abs(a[i][index[k]]) > max {
                kk = k
                max = math.Abs(a[i][index[k]])
            }
        }

        index[i], index[kk] = index[kk], index[i]

        r = a[i][index[i]]

        if r == 0 {
            if b[i] == 0 {
                fmt.Println("a lot of solutions")
            } else {
                fmt.Println("no solutions")
            }
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        for j := 0; j < len(a[i]); j++ {
            a[i][index[j]] /= r
        }
        b[i] /= r

        //concurrency
        chunk := len(a) / workers
        for w := 0; w < workers; w++ {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func(start int) {
                end := start + chunk
                if end > len(a) {
                    end = len(a)
                }
                for k := start; k < end; k++ {
                    r := a[k][index[i]]

                    for j := 0; j < len(a[i]); j++ {
                        a[k][index[j]] = a[k][index[j]] - a[i][index[j]]*r
                    }
                    b[k] = b[k] - b[i]*r
                }
                wg.Done()
            }(w*chunk + i + 1)

        }
        wg.Wait()

    }

    var x vector = make(vector, len(b))

    for i := len(a) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        x[i] = b[i]

        for j := i + 1; j < len(a); j++ {
            x[i] = x[i] - (x[j] * a[i][index[j]])
        }
    }

    result := make([]string, len(x))
    for i, val := range index {
        result[val] = fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", x[i])
    }
    fmt.Println(time.Since(start))
}
```

With a matrix size of N = 3000, the program with concurrency, calculates a system of linear equations in **19 seconds**, while the usual version spends **43 seconds**!!!